# Uninvited Guest Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction

This is a tricky riddle...

> Queen Elizabeth organized a royal party.
>
> To Avoid uninvited guest royal family set a password.
>   Wayne (an uninvited person) plan to enter the party. He stand nearby the door.
>
> First guest comes, the security person said 'twelve' and guest replied with six.
>   Second guest comes , the security person said 'six' and guest replied with 'three'.
>
> Wayne thought is enough and he walked to the entry point. The security person said 'eight' , Wayne replied smilingly 'four'.
>   He was immediately thrown out of the party.
>
> why ?

```
 Why could he possibly be thrown out if he answered correct?
```

Answer (score 5):

Wayne should have said

> Five, as the response is the number of letters in the original number.